# Method or Data Member Not found for every control or event suddenly

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was working on my access project and I closed and restarted it. I do not think that I changed anything in there. I have a button click event in the form that gets values like

`me.num`, `me.amount` etc.

On button click however I am getting an error:

> Method or Data Member Not found for every control or event

on every single controls.

I made sure that all of my references are there

[image]

What is really wierd is that if I type `me.` access automatically brings up all the field names that it says it cannot find when the button click event fires.

I have deleted the button and recreated a new one and pasted the code but it gives the same error.

How is this even possible?

Comment: Is the error literally "*Method or Data Member Not found for every control or event*"? Might be helpful to see the line that the error show up on.

Comment: Run Compact & Repair, maybe even decompile then recompile. There may be corruption that cannot be fixed without recreating something, maybe even require new db file. Start by building another form and see if its code finds fields/controls.

Comment: I found out the issue but not sure why Access misguided me. Posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had about 9 or 10 references to the form controls and I had incorrect name on one of them.

```
strSelectQuery = "SELECT " & Me.ID & " ," & Nz(Me.Date, "Null") & " ," & Me.User & " ," & Nz(Me.Name, "Null") & _
    " ,'" & Me.Val & "' ,'" & Me.JOB & "' , INVD.ID,0,0,0, '" & Me.vis & "', '" & me.vis2 & "', '" & ind & "', '" & Me.vis4 & "', '" & Me.vid3 & "', '" & Me.vid5 & "'" & _
    " FROM Table1"
```

All of the control names were correct except `me.vis2` was supposed to be `me.vid2`, however Access was not highlighting that field but was highlighting other controls that were not incorrect.

I had to remove everything and type it one at at time to find out the issue.

Throwing error on correct field names completely threw me off as I thought something was wrong with Access.

If someone could explain why this happens that would be great.